# Request from Rest API using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I created a Rest API using express that connects to mongodb.

It works perfectly with postman.

Then i created a simple web app with vue, and tried to get a response from the api using axios, but i get an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ... has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

i tried using multiple solutions including [**cors**](https://github.com/expressjs/cors), and setting res.header.

***index.js***

```
const app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    next()
})

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'))

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(422).send({error: err.message + req.params})
})

app.listen(process.env.port || 4000, () => {
    console.log('listening...')
})
```

***vue component***

```
import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            info: 'omg',
        }),
        mounted() {
            axios.get('localhost:4000')
                 .then(response => (this.info = response))
                 .catch(error => console.log(error))
        },
    }
```

**How can i get data from the api?**

Comment: with that cors setup you're still getting the same cors error you listed in the catch block of axios?

Comment: yup...exactly the same error and i tried a lot of different configurations for cors, non work 

Comment: Are you using authentication in express? If so you need to set "withCredentials: true" in axios in order to tell axios to send the authentication cookie.

Comment: no, my express configuration is exactly as described in the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify protocol scheme: `http://`, your cors settings are not the issue.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000')
```

Also you requests just `localhost:4000` and as I see your server hasn't `/` route - you will get 404 error.

Comment: Wow, that literally solved the problem immediately!
 thank you so much!